# Linker errors when using the MySQL Connector C++ lib, which I correctly built in Visual Studio 2022 and the Windows Forms CLR

Tags: c++, winforms, mysql-connector

I am trying to compile a Windows Forms C++ project in Visual Studio 2022. But the linker generates a lot of errors. But if I don't declare any libraries, the Windows Forms C++ project compiles and runs normally.

```
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_art_resultset.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB '' was not found with 'mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_art_resultset.obj)' or at ''; linking object as if no debug info
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_prepared_statement.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB '' was not found with 'mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_prepared_statement.obj)' or at ''; linking object as if no debug info
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_connection.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB '' was not found with 'mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_connection.obj)' or at ''; linking object as if no debug info
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_util.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB '' was not found with 'mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_util.obj)' or at ''; linking object as if no debug info
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_warning.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB '' was not found with 'mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_warning.obj)' or at ''; linking object as if no debug info
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_ps_resultset.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB '' was not found with 'mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_ps_resultset.obj)' or at ''; linking object as if no debug info
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_art_rset_metadata.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB '' was not found with 'mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_art_rset_metadata.obj)' or at ''; linking object as if no debug info
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_resultbind.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB '' was not found with 'mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_resultbind.obj)' or at ''; linking object as if no debug info
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_ps_resultset_metadata.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB '' was not found with 'mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_ps_resultset_metadata.obj)' or at ''; linking object as if no debug info
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_parameter_metadata.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB '' was not found with 'mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_parameter_metadata.obj)' or at ''; linking object as if no debug info
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_uri.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB '' was not found with 'mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_uri.obj)' or at ''; linking object as if no debug info
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_metadata.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB '' was not found with 'mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_metadata.obj)' or at ''; linking object as if no debug info
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_statement.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB '' was not found with 'mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_statement.obj)' or at ''; linking object as if no debug info
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_debug.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB '' was not found with 'mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_debug.obj)' or at ''; linking object as if no debug info
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_resultset.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB '' was not found with 'mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_resultset.obj)' or at ''; linking object as if no debug info
1>mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_resultset_metadata.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB '' was not found with 'mysqlcppconn-static.lib(mysql_resultset_metadata.obj)' or at ''; linking object as if no debug info
```

I've tried fixing the error via

```
#pragma comment(lib, "mysqlcppconn-static.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "mysqlclient.lib")
```

but it still appears and the project won't start. I have tried to fix this problem, but there is no way I can do it.  Can you help me.

The most interesting thing is that the error appears only when some header file is connected. I don't have pointers in my code, I don't use them now. This error points to the code of the utility.cpp file. To the "_onexit" function.

Here's the function itself :

```
extern "C" _onexit_t __cdecl _onexit(_In_opt_ _onexit_t const function)
{
    _PVFV* const onexit_first = module_local_atexit_table._first;

    if (onexit_first == reinterpret_cast<_PVFV*>(-1))
    {
        return _crt_atexit(reinterpret_cast<_PVFV>(function)) == 0
            ? function
            : nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        return _register_onexit_function(&module_local_atexit_table, function) == 0
            ? function
            : nullptr;
    }
}
```

Minimum code that can reproduce the error:

```
#include "MyForm.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

int main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    MySqlCPPTest::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(% form);
}
```

Comment: I don't see errors. I see only warnings.

Comment: Though this is a warning, but I am not getting Windows Forms to run using MySql Connector C++. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You question does not contain any information useful for diagnosing the troubles. If the project won't start, it should raise errors in the debug window.

Comment: The only thing I managed to find in debug mode is these messages - "A breakpoint instruction (__debugbreak() statement or a similar call) was executed in MySqlCPPTest.exe."-"Exception thrown at 0x00007FFFFFF212A635 (ntdll.dll) in MySqlCPPTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation accessing location 0x0000000000000000. " - " Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFFFFF21FC1A9 (ntdll.dll) in MySqlCPPTest.exe: 0xC0000374: Heap was corrupted (parameters: 0x00007FFFFFF22728B0).""

Comment: *Access violation accessing location 0x0000000000000000* is dereferencing the null pointer somewhere in the code. *Heap was corrupted* - yet another improper memory usage somewhere in the code.

Comment: Yes, I see this error. And the most interesting thing is that it appears only when some header file is connected. I don't have pointers in my code, I don't use them now. This error points to the code of the utility.cpp file. To the "_onexi" function.

Comment: The function code itself :
```
extern "C" _onexit_t __cdecl _onexit(_In_opt_ _onexit_t const function)
{
    _PVFV* const onexit_first = module_local_atexit_table._first;

    if (onexit_first == reinterpret_cast<_PVFV*>>(-1))
    {
        return _crt_atexit(reinterpret_cast<_PVFV>(function)) == 0
            ? function
            : nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        return _register_onexit_function(&module_local_atexit_table, function) == 0
            ? function
            : nullptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: [edit] and post the code in the question.